# Rollup: How to resolve CSS imports from inside node_modules

Tags: javascript, build, svelte, rollup

I have a rollup config (descended from the Sapper starter) that works well, but I just added the svelte-filepond component and it is not resolving it's CSS.

I see the following 404 in the client:

```
http://localhost:3000/filepond/dist/filepond.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Apparently, the component is importing the CSS but it is not found.

I tried using the `rollup-plugin-styles` plugin, but that didn't seem to work.

Looking through the sources, it looks like there is a `@import` statement in the CSS.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969233/how-to-use-css-import-in-rollup?

Comment: Look at includePaths, it could be the solution to this. What css preprocessor are you using?

Comment: my issue was that i had explicitly added the file to the external array of rollup. **facepalm** adding the '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve' solved my issue when i removed them from the external array.